# AngularJS: Watch a property of the parent scope

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm quite new to AngularJS and I'm trying to understand a few things.
First of all, I have my controller of which I will place a snippet here:

```
var OfficeUIRibbon = angular.module('OfficeUIRibbon');

// Defines the OfficeUIRibbon controller for the application.
OfficeUIRibbon.controller('OfficeUIRibbon', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    var ribbon = this;

    ribbon.setApplicationMenuAsActive = function() {
        ribbon.applicationMenuActive = true;
    }
}
```

Then I have a directive:

```
var OfficeUIRibbon = angular.module('OfficeUIRibbon');

OfficeUIRibbon.directive('ribbonApplicationMenu', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            data: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: function(element, attributes) {
            return attributes.templateurl;
        }
    }
});
```

The directive is called like this:

```
<ribbon-application-menu templateUrl="/OfficeUI.Beta/Resources/Templates/ApplicationMenu.html"     data="/OfficeUI.Beta/Resources/JSon/Ribbon/ribbon.json"></ribbon-application-menu>
```

This does all work and in my template for the directive, the following is placed:

```
<div id="application" id="applicationMenuHolder" ng-controller="OfficeUIRibbon as OfficeUIRibbon" ng-show="OfficeUIRibbon.applicationMenuActive"...
```

From inside another element, when I execute a click a function on my controller is executed:

```
ng-click="OfficeUIRibbon.setApplicationMenuAsActive()"
```

Here's the directive from the other element:

```
OfficeUIRibbon.directive('ribbon', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: false,
        scope: {
            data: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: function(element, attributes) {
            return attributes.templateurl;
        }
    }
});
```

This function does change the property "applicationMenuActive" on the ribbon itself, which should make the item in the directive template show up.

However, this is not working. I'm guessing I need to watch this property so the view get's updated accordingly.

Anyone has an idea on how this could be done?

Comment: Please recheck the question because there was a typo in it. Maybe it's clearer right now. If it's not clear enough, don't hesitate to ask. I've put the wrong directive by accident but it's corrected right now.

Comment: `From inside another element, when I execute a click a function on my controller is executed:` How is _the other element_ related to the directive template?

Comment: The directive outputs a custom HTML template. I want this template to show only when I modify a value in the scope. So I have element 1. When I click on a button, a scope variable is changed. In the template that the directive outputs, there's an ng-show on the property that has been changed. However, when it's changed, the ng-show does not show the element. I hope this is more clear right now? In case it isn't, don't hesitate to ask. I would be very happy if I can get something working?

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do, what i am asking is where is the element `I have element 1. When I click on a button, a scope variable is changed.`

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Sorry but I'm a n00b in AngularJS. I create a plunker. Give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: What i am asking is you keep saying `When I click on a button, a scope variable is changed` where is that button? is it inside the directive template or somewhere outside? You are not showing us that part

Comment: The other element is in fact another template which is executed from within another directive. Do you need any additional information?

Comment: I've updated the question with the directive from within the variable of the scope is updated.

Comment: Hmmm, I don't manage to create a 'Plunker', it's always freezing. I hope you can provide me some help without a plunker script.

Comment: Question is still not clear to me on where do you use the ribbon directive and how does it trigger the controller function. You can use stackoverflow code snippet tool to create a demo.

Comment: I'll try to explain a bit more. I'm recreating the OfficeUI ribbon in AngularJS. I have a directive which renders the ribbon and I have a directive which renders the contents behind the first tab. Both directives return a template. In the ribbon template, I have an ng-click on the first tab item so a function in the controller is executed. This function does change a variable to true. In the other directive (uses the same controller) has a ng-show on the top DIV element to show only when the property is set to true. But the problem is that both directives uses Isolated scope. Make more sense?

Comment: I guess the problem here is that the once the directive it's executed, the ng-show isn't executed anymore :s

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68769/discussion-between-complexity-and-psl).

Comment: ok. it wont work like that because both the directives have different instances of the controller `OfficeUIRibbon` and both are isolate scoped.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. But how do I pass a controller instance from one directive to another then? You mind going to the chat corner?

Comment: I cannot access chat right now.. :( It is blocked here.

Comment: Ok, now problem. So what you're saying is that the above solution will not work due to 2 different instances of the controller. But, how do I pass my controller instance then from my first directive to my second directive?

Comment: You can require a parent controller. But I don't know how these are all structured

Comment: Ok, So I need to find out for myself :-). Well, I do thank you for all the effort that you've put in the question.